# How to integrate Modeler of Bpmn-js into React

Tags: reactjs, components, bpmn

I'm trying to integrate a Bpmn Modeler into my React app but so far it's not successful. It seems to work with the Viewer example I've also found in SO in the other thread, but with a Modeler, I can't. Can anyone help me out or point to the right direction?

This is my sample code on codeandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/j398qkv0zv , which is following from this example https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/modeler

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Hoping it's Not too Late. Please check the codesndbox below, https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-lake-szfyo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this helped me a lot. Noob question: For react projects you don't recommend to use the component tag element <ReactBpmn.... /> as its described in the docs https://github.com/bpmn-io/react-bpmn ?

Comment: Hello @saomi, I am happy that you've found the answer helpful. In my case, the <ReactBpmn/> did not meet my needs so I had to find another option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard use bpmn-js with react, I made a functional component version of modeler + custom properties panel in latest version of react.

you can find it here https://github.com/bpmn-io/react-bpmn

```
function App() {  
  const container = useRef(null);
  const [ modeler, setModeler ] = useState(null)

  let modelerInstance = null

  useEffect(() => {
    if (modelerInstance) return

    modelerInstance = new Modeler({
      container: container.current,
      moddleExtensions: {
        custom: customModdleExtension
      },
      keyboard: {
        bindTo: document.body
      }
    });
    modelerInstance
      .importXML(diagramXML)
      .then(({ warnings }) => {
        if (warnings.length) {
          console.warn(warnings);
        }
  
        modelerInstance
          .get("canvas")
          .zoom("fit-viewport");
      });  

    setModeler(modelerInstance)

    return () => {
      modeler?.destroy();
    }
  }, [])

  const handleExport = () => {
    modeler.saveXML({ format: true }).then(({ xml, error }) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
      }

      console.log('UPDATE XML:', xml)
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="modeler-parent">
      <div id="modeler-container" ref={container}></div>
      <div id="properties-container">
        <button onClick={handleExport}>Export BPMN</button>
        {modeler && 
          <PropertiesView modeler={ modeler } />
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```